# How can I fix an AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes' ​

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
def detect_face_mask(img):
    
    y_pred = model.predict_classes(img.reshape(1,224,224,3))
    
    
    return y_pred

 sample1 = cv2.imread('sample/1.jpg')
 sample1 = cv2.resize(sample1,(224,224))

 detect_face_mask(sample1)
```

- 

Last line returns error "AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'"

This exact code was working not, so struggling a bit, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a `keras` `Sequential` class, the method `predict_classes` has been deprecated for over two years now.

Try

```
y_pred = model.predict(img)
```

and then for the classes you can use something like

```
y_classes = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

depending on your specific `img` data.